# Javascript Delete item on sparse array and adjust length error

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a sparse Array. 
I use delete array[id] and I also want to adjust the length of the array after deletions. This is a pseudocode.

```
....
deleted =0; 
...
if (condition) { delete array[id]; deleted++;}
...
array.length-=deleted;
```

Ok. I dont know what happen, the array has the expected length but ... it is empty! 
Any idea what is happen?

Comment: You might want to use `Array.prototype.splice()` instead

Answer (score 2):

Right way to delete an element from sparse array is :

```
arr.forEach(elm,index){

//delete index element
delete arr[index]

}
```

This removes the element but leaves the array size same

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it manually and don't care about the order of items, the following is much faster than splice, but this messes up your order:

```
array[id] = array[array.length-1]; // copy last item to the index you want gone
array.pop(); // rremove the last item
```

The length of the array is automatically correct.

If you want to keep your order do what zerkms said and use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
 array.splice(id, 1);
```

The first parameter is the index from where you start. The second parameter is how many items you delete.

The length of the array is also correct.